# How to use csv writerow while appending xlrd cell value Python

Tags: python, excel, csv, for-loop

I wrote the following function that copies data from numerous excel files and copies them to csv. I am having trouble appending the "refresh_date_value" from a single cell in excel and iterating with writerow to include that date value with every row in my csv output. Currently it takes the "refresh_date_value" and splits every character into seperate columns. For example, the output files puts every character in its own column [2, 0, 2, 0, /, 0, 6....]. I'd just like to have the entire date in one column for each row. The "refresh_date_value" is a date time object so I didn't know how to join in writerow without turning it into a list. I've found some examples on Stack similar, but have been unable to get the desired results. Thank you in advance.

'''

```
def append_all(input_directory):
    for file in os.listdir(input_directory):
        if bool(re.search(pattern, file)) == True:
            in_fpath = os.path.join(input_directory, file)
            out_fpath = os.path.join(input_directory, 'history.csv')
            wrkbk = xlrd.open_workbook(in_fpath)
            wrksht = wrkbk.sheet_by_name('importer')
            
            refresh_date_float = wrksht.cell_value(1,4)
            refresh_date_value = xlrd.xldate_as_datetime(refresh_date_float, wrkbk.datemode).strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
            
            if os.path.isfile(out_fpath) == False:
                with open(out_fpath, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
                    wr = csv.writer(csvfile)
                    for rownum in range(3, wrksht.nrows):   
                        wr.writerow(wrksht.row_values(rownum) + list(refresh_date_value))
                        # Start append data
            else:
                with open(out_fpath, 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
                    wr = csv.writer(csvfile)
                    for rownum in range(4, wrksht.nrows):
                        wr.writerow(wrksht.row_values(rownum)  + list(refresh_date_value))
                        
    csvfile.close()
    print('process complete')
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
wr.writerow(list(.row_values(rownum)) + [refresh_date_value])
```

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney my apologies. You are absolutely right. Thank you for the direction and proper SO etiquette.